# How can I get back to my old level?

Tags: borderlands-2

I read somewhere that after killing Handsome Jack and the Warrior, if you did not click on the True Vault Hunter mode, you could still access it by just starting a new game and you would still have all your XP's, current level, weapons, etc. Well, I did, and I lost **everything**!  And to top it off, I had to start from scratch, level 1! Is there any way I can still get back to my current level of 37 again, Or is all that "work" lost for good?

Comment: I played VH mode and very soon after went back to Playthrough 1, and had my Skills reset with only 1 to spend, just like the op. I spent the one, then exited the game normally (saving), and started a game again (Continue) and all my skill points came back so I could respend them again. Try that to see if they come back for you too.

Comment: @Mufasa The issue with the skills points resetting was fixed in Update 1.2.0 Released 11/13/2012

Answer (score 5):

I reckon you're starting a New Game, which will start a new character from Level 1.

To change from Normal Mode to True Vault Hunter mode, go to the Main Menu > Select Character > Select your character which has finished Normal Mode > Select 'True Vault Hunter Mode' as your Playthrough mode: [image]